# Frontend user profiles for a WP/Gatsby website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gatsby

I am working on a project that will include front end user profiles for our clients, in which there will include a custom user-specific dashboard and a subscription based e-commerce payment system.

I've figured that using JWT is the best option to secure the private JSON data for each user, however I'm unsure of how to actually create these profiles. Must I use a plugin? What would be recommended?

Currently I have set up my development environment to pull in pages and posts from WordPress, but I am looking for direction in planning out these next steps - ideally without the use of a WP plugin

Comment: You should pull user data client-side for security. Gatsby is just React - you can build client-side applications just like you would in a React app. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

The information I was looking for was provided by @Robin Métral as a comment. I need to add app functionality to the website - as documented in the Gatsby resources here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-app-and-website-functionality/

I have decided that Client-only Routes & User Authentication is the most appropriate solution: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/